# Show a html page within full screen

Tags: html, css

This is my html site https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/168659703/kappe/without_sidebar/index.html

Currently it is not fit to the full screen.  I could not understand how it is calculate the height of the screen. I want that it will fit to the full screen. That means no horizontal scroll bar. Please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: I am not seeing a horizontal scroll bar, even when I shrink the size of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
body
{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Comment: No luck. I am stack. Please tell me the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
body
{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```